# Foreach en controlador solo itera el primer resultado- Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un foreach ejectuntandose dentro de un método de un controlador, pero este solo me itera el primer resultado.

Por favor ayúdenme a entender soy novato.

Este es el método del controlador.

```
public function descargar(Request $request)
{
    $cliente_id = request('cliente_id');
    // $reportes = Factura::where("cliente_id", "=", $cliente_id)->orderBy('cliente_id' ,'ASC')->get();
    $reportes = Factura::all();
    if (request('archivo') == '1') {


    foreach($reportes as $reporte){
        return $reporte->rnc_cedula;
    }
}
```

}

Solo me arroja el primer resultado:

12345678919

Habiendo mas registros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El return implica una acción de cierre o terminación, por eso cuando itera el primer resultado el lenguaje interpreta que su función en el foreach termino

si lo que deseas es imprimir los resultados puedes usar el metodo print() o guardar estos valores en un nuevo array con la función array_push()

Comment: Si tienes razon. Olvide eso tan importante. Muchas gracias.